# Limits of difference quotient

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous,
then $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h) = f(x)$
then what is the $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$?

Does this limit always exist?

can anyone provides me a continuous f(x) where this limit exists and another continuous f(x) where it does not exist?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term of derivative?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes

Comment: Then you're basically asking for examples of a differentiable function and one which is not differentiable.

Comment: If you had made some attempt you would have come up with an example for the first case at least. (How about $f\equiv 0$?) I am voting this question for closure.

Comment: It seems a bit odd that this guy has posted [questions about muntivariable integral calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809220/how-to-integrate-iint-d-4x2-y2-dxdy-on-d-z-1-leq-1) yet apparently is confused by this fairly simple high school calculus problem? Seems like this might be a troll question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider both $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$. Check continuity and compute the above limit.